# {{mailServerNotLoadingTemplates}}

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

Received this email, and the placeholder was not replaced.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Thanks for the report, we've paused the batch and have identified the root cause. The process we use to test these emails used a different code path for deserializing the data used by the template to that used in production and so we never picked it up during QA.

I've just pushed a build that addresses that issue, run a test batch using the production code paths and verified that all is well.

Sadly we just sent 6270 of these out; I'll see if there's anything we plan to do about that.

Comment: Well, several email providers allow retracting emails before they're read.

Comment: @Shadow or maybe send out apology emails - bonus points if it also has placeholders: "Dear {{name}},... In our last email to you..." ;-) (I've actually had a bank do that to me!)

Comment: @Jon or a T-shirt instead of email. People would much prefer it. ;-)

Comment: A brand new t-shirt but just with {{logo}} on it... I'd be up for one of those...

Comment: "we never picked it up during QA" - I thought those 6000 emails were QA :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz ssshhhhh, don't go letting out all our secrets!