# Why are job advertisement emails being sent under the "Tips & Recommendations" subscription?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, email

I just received an email from "do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email" with the subject line "Live + Work Anywhere: find remote or visa jobs", encouraging me to browse jobs and listing four in particular. In the footer, the reason for the email is given as:

> This message was sent to [my email address] because you subscribed to Tips & Recommendations on Stack Overflow

I don't mind the email, but job ads isn't what I would expect from "Tips & Recommendations" for Stack Overflow, especially when the four options for managing emails are:

- New Features - New products and major updates. Only few a year.
- Tips & Recommendations - Timely advice to help you make the most of our features.
- Jobs Announcements - Be the first to learn about new Jobs features.
- Developer Story Status - Updates about your Developer Story (no trailing period?)

Surely this email would have been more appropriately categorised as "Job Announcements", as it is a combination of informing me about a new Jobs feature (the ability to filter job listings by "remote work") and advertising several job listings to me?

Comment: Surely telling you how to "find remote or visa jobs" is a tip?

Comment: So it's not a "new Jobs feature" but rather "Timely advice to help you make the most of" an existing feature"? I can buy that. What put me off is that I don't think of "Jobs" as a feature of Stack Overflow - to my mind it's a separate product, but perhaps this was "timely advice" to change the way I think about it ;)

Comment: Well my comment was slightly tongue-in-cheek, but I guess it's still a valid point. As for jobs not being a part of SO, I'm sure the SO staff would point out that it's a huge and integral part, their vision is there to try to make devs lives better in all ways.

Comment: @KendallLister Jobs is definitely part of SO. That is why it's `http://stackoverflow.com/jobs`, just like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`

Comment: Yes, I merely expressed that I don't yet think of it this way, and that I'm catching up with reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote/visa filters aren't a new feature; they've been there since the dawn of time (well since /jobs was part of Joel on Software), so this email wasn't really appropriate for the 'Job Announcements' bucket. The 'Tips & Recommendations' bucket is there for exactly this kind of email - *"Hey, did you know you can do this? And here's a few job recommendations that we think match your [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current)"*.

This particular email was only targeted at users that were marked as actively looking or open, but not actively looking for a job and that were opted into the 'Tips & Recommendations' bucket.

Comment: If 'Tips & Recommendations' consist of merely a job dump (which we see on the right of SO, anyway) - I think that's somewhat misleading in it's description. Guess it's time to turn off that subscription

Comment: Yes, I can't recall receiving any other tips or recommendations. If I had, that might have primed me to regard this email as just another one of those. I guess my follow-up question is "Why is there a special category for emails about new Jobs features when there is already a category for all new features?".

Comment: Regardless, this is the officially correct answer, so... ticked!

Answer (score 3):

The email was also badly broken - most of the "clickable" links aren't clickable.  Looking at the source, you can see they have text like this: `{{remoteJobsUrl}}` which smacks of a broken templating stage.

Comment: I'm not seeing any broken links. I received the email 8 hours ago and all of the links go through the URL `http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?upn=...`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349020/mailservernotloadingtemplates

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - StackExchange already admitted they they sent out a few thousand broken emails.  Generally in tech, "It works for me" is no proof whatsoever that everything is working.

Comment: Hey Tom this post was not about the broken images, it was an entirely different perspective, I think it made more sense as a comment rather than an answer.