# Why is there a special category for emails about new Jobs features when there is already a category for all new features?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, email

The four options for managing emails from Stack Overflow are:

- New Features - New products and major updates. Only few a year.
- Tips & Recommendations - Timely advice to help you make the most of our features.
- Jobs Announcements - Be the first to learn about new Jobs features.
- Developer Story Status - Updates about your Developer Story

Why is there a separate category for new Jobs features announcements, and why can't such announcements be sent under the "New Features" category? Emails about old Jobs features are sent under "Tips & Recommendations" without a special Jobs category (see [Why are job advertisement emails being sent under the "Tips & Recommendations" subscription?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349023/why-are-job-advertisement-emails-being-sent-under-the-tips-recommendations-s)), so having a special category for new Jobs features announcements feels unnecessary and confusing (especially because the category name "Jobs Announcements" seems at first glance that it would be for announcing jobs, not new features).

Comment: Without any special knowledge of this, I would assume that the Jobs team is planning on adding new features and wants to allow for folks without any particular interest in them to opt out... So what's the issue?

Comment: It's confusing - I now know that Jobs is now part of Stack Overflow, but I didn't until yesterday's email and my subsequently asking about it here. Also, if it's thought that people would like to opt out of announcements about new Job-specific features, it seems reasonable to assume that they might also like to opt out of Jobs-specific tips and recommendations, which is not currently possible.

Comment: Smells like a FEATURE-REQUEST!

Comment: Sure, but I thought I'd first ask whether there is a reason for the current arrangement that explains the apparent inconsistency.

Comment: Someone may be interested in SO as a job search portal and not care at all about Q&A features that would be announced under New Features.

Comment: So that person will be getting tips and recommendations about Q&A that they're not interested in - if the separation is important it should be consistent, to reduce unwanted emails and confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're planning to merge these two email buckets together. I'm not sure on timelines yet, but it'll be soon - we're doing a lot of work around email right now.