# Why did I get a job email?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I'm not currently looking for a job, but got this email:

[image]

So I checked to make sure my email and job settings were correct:

[image]

And my job settings:

[image]

Why did I get an email from Stack Overflow about jobs when I've turned them off in my email and job settings?

Comment: Because SO really **really** likes that job for you

Comment: checking it out, I'll post back with details... we don't want you to receive emails if you don't want to receive emails. It only hurts us :)

Comment: I had a similar email a few days ago in spite of settings (just haven't had time to make a meta post about it).

Comment: Yes, same goes for me.

Comment: You don't have Tips&Reccommendations enabled either,
 as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349023/why-are-job-advertisement-emails-being-sent-under-the-tips-recommendations-s?rq=1) ?

Comment: I didn't receive an email and am starting to feel left out. :|

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright, I have a response as to why you received this email. We've been working hard on sending emails in a way that's relevant for our users. Every time we send an email a user doesn't want we feel pretty bad.

You received the email because:

1. You showed activity on /jobs recently
2. You're subscribed to the general tips & recommendations bucket

#### You showed activity on /jobs recently

<strike>I agree with you that this isn't right and we'll change it. If you said you don't want to hear about us, you shouldn't hear about us.</strike>

I just put it in here to share our reasoning of why you were selected as a recipient of this email.

**UPDATE**: We've changed that (a couple days now, I forgot to update this answer). If you said you're not interested in jobs, you will not receive jobs emails. If you ever do, it's a bug and please report it so that we can fix it.

#### You're subscribed to the general tips & recommendations bucket

As part of these new efforts, we're going to release a new way to manage your email preferences where it's clearer what you're opted into.

Our current interface has the "Tips & Recommendations" bucket inside of "Q&A Emails"

But that bucket is used to share tips & recommendations about all our features (not only Q&A, as that section implies). This will be fixed shortly with the new UI. Feel free to opt out of this bucket if you don't want to receive tips and recommendations related to our products.

We're working on it, and thanks to your post we won't be sending this email to other people in the same situation.

#### UPDATE: We have shipped the new email preferences

You can read [our post about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature). We also moved this email to the cleaner "Recommended Jobs" bucket (it no longer belongs to "Tips & Recommendations", where you can expect to receive... well, tips and recommendations).

If you want to update your preferences, you [can do so here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

Comment: Thanks for the timely response. I happen to misclick the Jobs tab on the homepage a lot, probably the activity. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: "Tips and recommendations" on "our features" doesn't really seem like it should include job alerts. Not only are those not really Stack Overflow's features, but especially since you already have a category for those. This bucket should be limited to things like ["new features have been added to the Jobs site"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352590/stack-overflow-jobs-update-july-20-2017).

Comment: @CodyGray hmm, I do see your point. I'll raise this issue internally.

Comment: Btw I got a really stupid recommendation (wrong job type, wrong location, wrong salary bucket)... you might want to tweak that matching a little bit more

Comment: @Sklivvz moar details please? Oh, and hai!

Comment: @DeanWard Hi! http://imgur.com/0fqijHh

Comment: @Sklivvz thanks, we're working on refining all the things now

Comment: @DeanWard, I was nearly certain the email was a fishing scam because the matches were so poor: France, Germany, New Mexico and Fortran!. I hope you'll have a separate opt-in/out option for these.

Comment: @Mike3d0g judging from our logs it looks like prior to that email being sent you didn't have any [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) at all. That means we fall back to your [Providence profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) which gives us an indication of your previous profile views. Unfortunately that doesn't give us much of an idea of your location. I'm discussing with the team whether we should be sending that email in the absence of strong matching data in the first place...

Comment: @Mike3d0g I see that you subsequently updated your match preferences so that should mean future matches are accurate. You can always opt out of these particular emails by unsubscribing from the **Job Recommendations** bucket in your email settings (https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

Comment: Thanks. When I got the email I don't think (or had forgotten) I was subscribed to Job Recommendations, so I thought it was phishing. If the first email sent comes a long time after someone checked the box, maybe it needs a notice that this is fresh even if the opt-in is old. FWIW, I'm excited about the service but was surprised about the email.

Comment: @CodyGray updated the answer to reflect the work we've been doing. We moved this email to a cleaner bucket to leave "Tips and recommendations" for tips and recommendations, as you pointed out. Thanks for that!